# My Volvo S40 2006 Immobilizer Not Releasing

Tags: brakes, volvo, emergency-brakes, s40

[image]

I have that fault in the Volvo S40 2006 so it does not give or release the lever when braking

<sub>Original text: Tengo esa falla en el volvo s40 2006 por eso no da estar ni libera la palanca al frenar</sub>

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please understand this is an English only site, so I have translated (hopefully correctly) your question for you. Is the immobilizer (e-brake) an electronic one? I'm not sure on your vehicle, thus the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the transponder located in the KEY or the Antenna Ring located at the KEY entry point. These two make up the immobilizer.

What you can try is to turn the key but WAIT 3s every single tick. This should reset the immobilizer. You may have to repeat this after a couple of months. I did it 2 - 3 times but with intervals of 3 months so the effort is low.

Comment: Gracias lo aré.